# REST API design beyond basic CRUD

Tags: json, api, rest

I am struggling trying to learn how to design restful services correctly. How do you handle things that are not purely simple CRUD and require a complex response? My toy example is

- A simple Inventory system receives a JSON message with an array of
  products and quantities to be taken from the inventory.
- Multiple inventory resources identified by the product id may their 
  quantities reduced by the requested amount  on each take request.
- Updates must be atomic in a transaction.
- Any subtractions that result in a negative inventory need to be
  communicated back to the client as that means a back order situation 
  exists.

The usual use case for this is when an order is committed on the order system and it must tell the inventory system to update. This update is partial because the  inventory quantity that  exists can only be known when the update is attempted.

There is no master resource to be updated since the inventory system knows nothing of an order.

The request might look something like 

PUT:  inventory/take 

or 

PATCH: inventory

I think PATCH may be the "correct" choice if you follow the REST guidelines but 
if I did use PATCH I should probably modify the JSON to be more generic with operations from what I read.

The JSON request body would look something like this

```
        [
          {
            productId: 1, 
            quantity: 2
          }
          {
            productId:  10, 
            quantity: 3
          } 
       ]
```

Any design guidance here would be appreciated especially as to how things are done in the real world or any helpful links to REST design that deal with with things more complex then CRUD would be appreciated.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Whether you should use PUT or PATCH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what the question is exactly, but here are a few elements of answer:

**`PUT` is idempotent** (or should be in theory). It means that if you PUT the same request twice, it should have no effect. It's obviously not the case here, since you're decreasing quantities at each request, so forget it.

You can either use `PATCH` or `POST` on your resource `/inventory`. Your JSON looks good for both `PATCH` and `POST`. It really depends if you want to be pragmatic (then use `POST`, it'll work everywhere) or idealistic (then use `PATCH`, it's cool and semantic).

Personally I think it would make more sense to send **negative** quantities when taking products out of the inventory, and **positive** quantities when restocking. That way you can use the same endpoint for both actions.

Regarding the response, personally I think it would make sense to return the list of **all the products passed in the request**, with the updated remaining quantity. For example:

```
[
  { productId: 1, remaining: 12 },
  { productId: 10, remaining: -1 }
]
```

Returning the same list of products as in the request has many advantages:

- your API is more versatile (if you only care about "back order" products for now, just look up for the rows with a negative value in `remaining` and ignore the rest)
- the response is useful whether you are adding or removing products from your inventory
- it's also a way to make sure that all the product IDs have been processed by the API. If a product ID is missing in the result, the API client can detect that something has gone wrong.

Comment: Good point on the idempotent put, I totally ignored that.

Comment: Also agree with the negative quantities.

Comment: If I choose to use a POST request as suggested then how do I differentiate between a request to create a new inventory item and the situation described above where I want to partially update a list of inventory items if both are a POST? Is it is all decided by the content of the message in the body or do I add an additional component to the URL like inventory/take? Do I have to return back a response with a list of the complete updated inventory items? I would rather return back the list of back ordered items if this is not a complete violation of REST principles.

Comment: What do you mean "create a new inventory item"? If you want to create products, make different endpoints `POST /products`, `PUT /product/:id`, `DELETE /product/:id`, etc. Otherwise, use positive/negative quantities to differentiate adding/removing products from the inventory as I suggested. I updated my answer about the response format.

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I keep products separate from the inventory of the product hence I have a product table and a inventory table. The inventory table is where I keep inventory and may be physically in a different DB from the product table. This is why I asked about the need for differentiating the type of POST request on inventory. I would want a POST request to create an inventory table row and a POST request to add or subtract from the available quantity.  I view inventory as a separate service related to product only by product id. Anyway I will keep reading. Thanks again

Comment: This is technical implementation, and should be hidden from the client. Ask yourself: should the client know if there is already a row with this product ID the inventory (maybe with quantity 0, maybe not)? Unless you want a specific response in this case, I think it should be the same API request: "hey inventory, I'm adding 3 objects of ID 10, I don't care if you must create a row or update the quantity, actually I don't even care what storage method you use, just do it".